# How to retrieve variable from swift class to objective c class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to retrieve some variables from my swift class in my objective c class. How can I do that.

I tried this but it doesn't retrieve the value when I debug it. And it says unresolved identifier while typing it in.

```
UGPaymentBankAccController *PaymentSwift = [[UGPaymentBankAccController alloc] init];
PaymentSwift.cityAddress.text
```

Comment: Is `cityAddress` a struct? If so, Swift structs are not accessible from Objective-C. Make this a class instead, or add convenience methods on the class to access the underlying properties of the struct.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook how do I do that

Comment: Just add another method to `UGPaymentBankAccController` like `func cityAddressText() -> String { return cityAddress.text }`

Comment: @daltonclaybrook would it just work or do I have to send it somehow. Because it goes from my UGPaymentBankAccController to my objective c class when a button gets hit

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I did that and it crashed

Comment: please add more details to this post like error message.